# mysql UPDATE MAX value of group using `open` value of MIN(id) of same group, multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to UPDATE the `open` value of MAX(id) of the group (`exchange, base_currency, quote_currency, DATE(created_at)`), using the value of `last` from the MIN(id) row of the same group.

```
id last open exchange base_curr quote_curr created_at

6  1.11 0.00 ex1      usd       yen        2018-07-29 03:00:00 --> update open with 1.14 (value of last from MIN(id) of group)          
5  1.09 0.00 ex1      usd       yen        2018-07-29 02:00:00
4  1.14 0.00 ex1      usd       yen        2018-07-29 01:00:00

3  0.49 0.00 ex2      yen       won        2018-07-29 03:00:00 --> update open with 0.50 (value of last from MIN(id) of group)
2  0.51 0.00 ex2      yen       won        2018-07-29 02:00:00
1  0.50 0.00 ex2      yen       won        2018-07-29 01:00:00
```

I understand how to get all the MIN(id) of the groups, but not sure *how to use the `last` values of the MIN(id)* rows to update the `open` value of MAX(id) of the group.

MAX(id) or MAX(created_at) would get me the latest rows of the groups.

```
SELECT MIN(id) as min_id, last
FROM tickers 
WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2018-07-29' 
GROUP BY exchange, base_currency, quote_currency, DATE(created_at)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the min/max in a subquery.  Then use another `join` to bring in the value from the min row:

```
update tickers t join
       (select exchange, base_curr, quote_curr, date(created_at) as created_at_date,
               max(id) as maxid, min(id) as minid
        from tickers t2
        group by exchange, base_curr, quote_curr, date(created_at)
       ) tt
       on tt.maxid = t.id join
       tickers tmin
       on tmin.id = tt.minid
    set t.open = tmin.last;
```

Comment: Wow Gordon, you're a genius, and my brain is about to explode. Thanks so much for your help.